# maven 3 + pmd fails when code has annotations and generics

Tags: java, maven-3, pmd

When I run `mvn pmd:pmd` I get an warning / error from PMD saying that the code cannot use generics, annotations or Enums with java 1.4 or 1.5. This is supposed to be a error when the targetJdk property is not set (which I did set).

Here is an example of the error I get

> [WARNING] Error while parsing /Users/augusto/Downloads/PMD-Clover2-Cobertura-Maven2-Test/PMDTest/src/main/java/org/xh/studies/quality/App.java: Can't use generics unless running in JDK 1.5 mode!

and here's a snippet of the pom I'm using (there's a link to the whole app below)

```
<build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.2</version>
           <configuration>
               <source>1.6</source>
               <target>1.6</target>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.5</version>
           <configuration>
               <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
</reporting>
```

I'm using Maven 3.0.2 on mac, with the latest java patch 1.6.0_24.

Click [here](http://lafqja.bay.livefilestore.com/y1p7r22eB4XvZg46BMoRP_uQEFugT4ZIpOy-tJE_gnmAiTJLDfOrWnjnrVBIx7OPXM-jE-ibBGe2vjQpXJFseYrQnhqhJP0jsdz/PMDTest-v2.zip?download&psid=1) to download the full project (8kb)

Comment: Why would you like to do mvn pmd:pmd instead of mvn package or mvn site ? Furthermore i recommed to update your Maven release to 3.0.3.

Comment: The code you published for download has a compile error (Missing import for List).

Comment: Sorry about that compilation issue, I deleted the line by mistake. I've updated the link with the fixed project. I'm running `mvn pmd:pmd` as I'll integrate it with the site later. This target should do the same when it's integrated (so it will throw the error). And I'm using maven 3.0.2 as it's bundled with the apple java JDK. I will try this on another platform (windows - maven 2.2.0) in a few minutes.

Comment: I get the same error with maven 3.0.3 on windows, but it works fine with maven 2.2.0. Something related to the site generation must have changed :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### EDIT (26/03/2014)

Since version 3.3 of the maven site plugin, maven can also use the old style configuration (and in fact the **maven 2** style is now recommended). Links: [docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html#Classic_configuration_Maven_2__3), [jira](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSITE-484).

---

### Original answer

Pain, the answer is that the site generation changed completely from maven 2 to maven 3. There  is an explanation on this [blog](http://www.wakaleo.com/blog/292-site-generation-in-maven-3). Note that `mvn pmd:pmd` doesn't work anyway with the new reporting configuration, but it works as part of the site generation.

And here's an example of a pom that works.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-beta-2</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportPlugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                            <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javancss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0</version>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jdepend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0-beta-2</version>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                            <sourceEncoding>utf-8</sourceEncoding>
                            <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens>
                            <targetJdk>${java-version}</targetJdk>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.2</version>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.6</version>
                    </plugin>

                </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```